# Disc-Shaped Component with two contacts

Tags: components

[image: weird Component]

I was wondering what is the name of this component, it really doesn't really have a part number, or anything similar so my research has really gone down to a low.  Researching *silver disk thingy* does not help either.

I found this part in a microwave, as well as in an old CRT TV, along with a bunch of other good parts.  What is the name, and purpose of this component?

Comment: It's a piezo disc, used to make basic beeping sounds, like the beep from the microwave when its finished. I'm not sure what its doing in your TV.

Comment: @SteveG SAME ON THE TV PART!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SteveG Its an old TV so I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as SteveG said

> It's a piezo disc, used to make basic beeping sounds, like the beep from the microwave when its finished.

You can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor).  It involves the piezoelectric effect which is more physics, but basically when a stress is applied to piezoelectric material a current is created.

Comment: One can use this as a noise maker or noise sensor near its resonant frequency. example http://www.communica.co.za/catalog/Details/P1362893234

Comment: @darkness - Alternatively, it can also be used to convert stress into a voltage.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Yes I was going to put that but thought current was better for the OP's level.